# Android Mockito TooManyActualInvocations

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, mockito

I am writing a testing code using the Mockito.
I faced the TooManyActualInvocations error.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
mockView.enableProgressBar(0);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at com.MyPresenterTest.doSomething(MyPresenterTest.kt:160)
But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at com.MyPresenter.doSomething(MyPresenter.kt:195)
```

Here is my sample code:

```
class MyPresenter(val view: MyView) {

    fun doSomething() {
        view.enableProgressBar(0)
        view.enableProgressBar(1)
        view.enableProgressBar(2)
        view.enableProgressBar(0)
    }

}
```

And here is my testing code:

```
@Test
fun doSomethingTest() {
    myPresenter.doSomething()

    Mockito.verify(mockView).enableProgressBar(0)
    Mockito.verify(mockView).enableProgressBar(1)
    Mockito.verify(mockView).enableProgressBar(2)
    Mockito.verify(mockView).enableProgressBar(0)
}
```

If I remove this line or change the value from '0' to other value which is not duplicated, it works fine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TooManyActualInvocations` means... too many actual invocations.

This has to work fine:

```
@Test
fun doSomethingTest() {
    myPresenter.doSomething()
    Mockito.verify(mockView, times(2)).enableProgressBar(0)
    Mockito.verify(mockView).enableProgressBar(1)
    Mockito.verify(mockView).enableProgressBar(2)
}
```

As `enableProgressBar` was called **twice with 0 argument**, then the assertion should be appropriate (should assert that it was called twice).
Or you can use some convenient Mockito methods such as `atLeastOnce()`, `atMost(2)`, etc. instead of straightforward `times` if you want to leave some space for implementation specifics.

Answer (score 4):

I found the resolution.

I didn't know about the "InOrder" interface.
Below code resolve my issue.

```
@Test
fun doSomethingTest() {
    myPresenter.doSomething()

    val inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mockView)

    inOrder.verify(mockView).enableProgressBar(0)
    inOrder.verify(mockView).enableProgressBar(1)
    inOrder.verify(mockView).enableProgressBar(2)
    inOrder.verify(mockView).enableProgressBar(0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my case, inOrder is better.